# PHP - How to access this complex nbt node object?

Tags: php, object

```
Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 10 [name] => ) 
[parent:Nbt\Node:private] => [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( 
[parent:Nbt\Node:private] => [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( 
[value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 9 [name] => i [payloadType] => 10 ) 
[parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] 
=> Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 2 [name] => id 
[value] => 367 ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* 
[children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => 
Array ( [type] => 1 [name] => Count [value] => 64 ) <-- How to access this??[parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object 
*RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Nbt\Node Object ( 
[value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 10 [name] => tag ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => 
Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 9 [name] => ench [payloadType] => 0 ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 3 [name] => HideFlags [value] => 254 ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 10 [name] => display ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 9 [name] => Lore [payloadType] => 8 ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [value] => �f�lCOMMON ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [1] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 8 [name] => Name [value] => �fEnchanted Rotten Flesh ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [3] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 10 [name] => ExtraAttributes ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [0] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 8 [name] => id [value] => ENCHANTED_ROTTEN_FLESH ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) ) ) ) ) [3] => Nbt\Node Object ( [value:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( [type] => 2 [name] => Damage [value] => 0 ) [parent:Nbt\Node:private] => Nbt\Node Object *RECURSION* [children:Nbt\Node:private] => Array ( ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Alright I know this may look very messy and not organised but right now I need some help to access the Count value from this complicated nbt object as an echo-able string using PHP.

if you want a cleaner look of this here you go:
[image]
I'm so sorry if this looks messy but I can't find a way to format this crazy node nbt object thing I tried a lot of different ways but none of them work, Would really appreciate it if anyone helped.
Thanks.

Comment: What's `nbt`? Is this what you get when you `var_dump()` the thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "...your big string... paste it here";   
$needle = "Count [value] =>";
if(($pos = strpos($str, $needle)) !== false){

    //echo "Count".substr($str,$pos+strlen($needle), )
    // For precise numeric return -digit- might be very large, like, 100000000
    // then
    // find Count [value] => then find the first occurance of )
    $newStr = substr($str, $pos+strlen($needle));
    if(($posEnd = strpos($newStr, ")")) !== false){
        echo "Count Value is ".trim(substr($newStr, 0, $posEnd));
    }

}
output: Count Value is 64
```

Comment: Um, this is not a string safi. This is an object it does not act like a string.

Comment: @Dave, sorry I made a mistake. Can you send me the lib you are using for creating nbt nodes? What function call are you using to receive this data? I want to replicate your results, then I'm sure I can solve the problem.